# Splitting fractions and aligning

Tags: equations, vertical-alignment

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
A=\frac{\splitfrac{a+b+5}{c+d}}{e}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```

How can I align the numerator so that 'c' starts from 'a'?

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! (I have edited your question (also made the example complete). Please check that I did not mess it up.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a solution that defines a macro called `\leftfrac`, which acts similarly to `\splitfrac` except that it left-aligns the rows.

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}% or some other suitable document class
%\usepackage{amsmath}  % 'amsmath' is loaded automatically by 'mathtools'
\usepackage{mathtools} % for '\splitfrac' macro
\newcommand\leftfrac[2]{%
   \begingroup\renewcommand\arraystretch{0.72}
   \begin{array}{@{}l@{}} #1\\#2 \end{array}\endgroup}

\begin{document}
\begin{equation}
A=\frac{\splitfrac{a+b+5}{c+d}}{e}
 =\frac{ \leftfrac{a+b+5}{c+d}}{e}
\end{equation}
\end{document}
```